# Error : "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden"

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, apache-axis, transport

In Eclipse,

"**org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden**" 
Error occured while trying to check out a project from svn. 
I colud not achieve this error and therefore I checked out the project from terminal using "svn -co" command.

But, the funny side is that, when I try to run the application from within Eclipse, I've faced w/ same error again right after I entered my credentials (username and passwd) and pressed "Login" button. The response was Invalid username/password on the JFrame, but credentials was not wrong.
This happens only in Eclipse. I can access SVN through web browser with same credentials. 
And I set proxies same as web browser.

I am not able to overcome this situation furthermore.

As to give info, I am on a virtual machine(MAC OS X Lion) through win7

Please provide some solutions to me asap.
Thanks.

**Here is the full stack-trace :**

> **org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Tunnel or SSL Forbidden**
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
>   ~[axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:194)
>   ~[axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
>   ~[axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   atorg.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:404)
>   ~[axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:231)
>   ~[axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:443)
>   ~[axis2-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
>   ~[axis2-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>   ~[axis2-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>   ~[axis2-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
>   ~[axis2-1.6.2.jar:na]
>   at org.apache.rahas.client.STSClient.requestSecurityToken(STSClient.java:154)
>   ~[rampart-trust-1.6.2.jar:1.6.2]
>   at tr.org.abc.sts.client.ESBSTSClient.issueToken(ESBSTSClient.java:103)
>   [ServiceClient-1.1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
>   at tr.org.abc.sts.client.ESBSTSClient.validateUser(ESBSTSClient.java:92)
>   [ServiceClient-1.1.0.7-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]

Comment: Thanks for both answers but the solution was our proxy settings. I will add details here soon. Not remembered now.

Answer (score 1):

I see this post is from a while ago. Not sure if you have resolved it yet.
I had a similar situation today with the same error via Eclipse, but it was on an app calling a SOAP WS endpoint through SSL, instead of SVN.

On further debugging, I found that was indeed the problem - null or wrong credentials. I would suggest you look back into your login credentials, SVN connectivity and other environmental issues with a notion that your credentials aren't reaching the SVN server.

Answer (score 0):

> "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 403 Error: Forbidden"
>   Error occured while trying to check out a project from svn.

Are you trying to checkout a project from SVN server using Axis2?

From [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Apache_Subversion):

> Apache HTTP Server as network server, WebDAV/Delta-V for protocol.
>   There is also an independent server process called svnserve that uses
>   a custom protocol over TCP/IP.

Apache Axis2 is designed for working with Web Services / SOAP / WSDL engine (client, server) is not intended for WebDAV services.

If you only want to checkout a project from a WebDAV SVN server in eclipse you can use [Subversive with SVNKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028095/compatibility-of-eclipse-luna-with-svn-1-6/29127250#29127250). If you are developing a SVN client to perform operations like checkout you can use a Java library like SVNKit or JSVN, both have an implementation of authenticators to login and work with SVN servers.