# Compatibility of Eclipse Luna with SVN 1.6

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I recently upgraded Eclipse to Luna, and one consequence of this is that Subversive upgraded to a version that uses SVNKit 1.7.8, which is not compatible with SVN 1.6.  When trying to import a project from SVN, it fails with "Unhandled event loop exception".

We are using SVN server 1.6, and it would not be easy to change this due to other dependencies.  Is there a way to install an older version of SVNKit and use it with the latest Eclipse?  The Subversive [installation instructions state that you can](http://eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php):

> If you wish, you can select multiple connectors and follow the installation procedure. After installation, you can switch the connector using the main menu item Window > Preferences > Team (tree node) > SVN (tree node) > SVN Connector (tab).

However, I don't seem to be able to add another SVN Connector and have it show up in the options.  I have added 1.3.8 via the dropins folder, and it didn't appear under the team options.

Is there a solution? Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Have you tried [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) instead of subversive? When I was using svn it was a little better than subversive.

Answer (score 8):

SVNKit 1.8.7 connector is 100% compatible with previous Subversion Server 1.6, as user714965 said, go to *Installation Details* and then **remove the SVN connectors and Subversive in order**, then restart eclipse.

**Go to the "Eclipse Marketplace"**

[image]

and **install Subversive**

[image]

Restar eclipse and go to `Window`->`Preferences` and select `Team`->`SVN` in the left panel, then automatically appears a window to select and **install the SVN connector**

[image]

**Select the latest version of connector (SVN Kit 1.8.7)** and install it, then restart eclipse and come back to `Window`->`Preferences`->`Team`->`SVN` and select the recent installed connector

[image]

You can checkout or share projects now.

[image]

[image]

Working with Subversion server 1.6

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer, but I am awarding the bounty to  @user714965 who got there first.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 6):

The [SVNKit website](http://svnkit.com/download.php) tells:

> Both SVNKit 1.7.13 and 1.8.8 support 1.6 and older working copy
>   formats without need to upgrade.

Seems as you should better update to one of the mentioned versions instead of downgrading to 1.6.

**UDPATE**

If you cannot directly update, try to remove SVNKit and reinstall it. I tried this with Luna:

`Help` -> `About` -> `Installation Details` -> Find `SVNKit` in the list and choose `Uninstall...`.

Then restart eclipse when prompted. When it comes back up the SVN connectors dialog appears and you can choose the current versions to install.

*Note*: Before doing this you might better make a backup copy of your eclipse folder.

Comment: Perhaps this will work, but actually doing that is the trick.  I have not been able to install any other version of SVNKit (it installs but doesn't show as an option in SVN Connectors), nor have I been able to upgrade Subversive (Eclipse tells me it is already installed and upgrade is not allowed).

Comment: Thanks.  I discovered that the problem was SVNKit discovery not showing up due to a firewall (and when it fails, it is not clear that something should have happened).  I can fix the firewall issue, though.

Answer (score 2):

As other people told you, SVN client 1.8 is compatible with SVN Server 1.6.
But you need to upgrade your previously imported SVN repository.

For my part, I just did the same as you (from Eclipse Indigo to Luna), but with SubClipse (from Tigris). And I had to upgrade my local SVN repository (which was less than 1.6) to a local SVN repository version 1.8.

To do so, I used [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/). Once installed, simply do right click on your SVN repo and select "Upgrade" (don't remember if it was directly accessible or if I had to look in "TortoiseSVN").

You will probably have to remove your projects from eclipse before importing them again because all hidden `.svn` directories will be deleted and only the one at the base of your SVN repository will remain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this wasn't needed.  It was updating the SVN connector.